# How do I install a software via Homebrew from .rb file

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm new to Homebrew (as in I know nothing, I'm a Radiologist). I need to install an additional software for my medical data analysis soft.
I have an .rb file and developers instructions but I'm stuck. Please help me to follow this. Where exactly should I download ruby file and how to run an installation from it?

Here's what I got.

```
# filename: xmedcon.rb.in                                                 #
                                                                       #
# UTILITY text: Medical Image Conversion Utility                          #                                                                     #
# # purpose     : the Homebrew formula template                             #
#                                                                         #
# project     : (X)MedCon by Erik Nolf                                    #
#                                                                         #
# credits     : contributed by Till-Karsten Hauser                        #
#               corrections by Cecil Yen                                  #
#                                                                         #
# usage       :                                                           #
#                                                                         #
#        1. download provided ".rb" file                                  #
#        2. rename to "xmedcon.rb"                                        #
#        3. install with "brew install --build-from-source xmedcon.rb"    #
#                                                                         #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

```
require 'formula'

class Xmedcon < Formula
  homepage 'http://xmedcon.sourceforge.net'
  url      'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xmedcon/XMedCon-Source/0.23.0/xmedcon-0.23.0.tar.bz2'
  version  '0.23.0'
  sha256   '835091243a242c3cc1fb5608b9540d07204bc74d42238ec4c067a5baa543ba39'

  depends_on 'glib'
  depends_on 'gtk+3'
  depends_on 'gdk-pixbuf'
  depends_on 'pkg-config'
  depends_on 'libpng'
  depends_on 'adwaita-icon-theme'

  depends_on 'autoconf' => :build
  depends_on 'automake' => :build
  depends_on 'libtool'  => :build

  def install
    system "autoreconf", "--force", "--install"
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--disable-dependency-tracking"
    system "make", "install"
  end
> end
```

So I downloaded this part

```
require 'formula'

class Xmedcon < Formula
  homepage 'http://xmedcon.sourceforge.net'
  url      'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xmedcon/XMedCon-Source/0.23.0/xmedcon-0.23.0.tar.bz2'
  version  '0.23.0'
  sha256   '835091243a242c3cc1fb5608b9540d07204bc74d42238ec4c067a5baa543ba39'

  depends_on 'glib'
  depends_on 'gtk+3'
  depends_on 'gdk-pixbuf'
  depends_on 'pkg-config'
  depends_on 'libpng'
  depends_on 'adwaita-icon-theme'

  depends_on 'autoconf' => :build
  depends_on 'automake' => :build
  depends_on 'libtool'  => :build

  def install
    system "autoreconf", "--force", "--install"
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--disable-dependency-tracking"
    system "make", "install"
  end
```

from GitHub and renamed it to "xmedcon.rb" as it was instructed...to my desktop, and than to Homebrew folder (¯_(ツ)_/¯)

and ran this command to my terminal and got

````
MacBook-Pro-USER:~ doc$ brew install --build-from- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/xmedcon.rb
Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "/usr/local/homebrew/library/taps/homebrew/xmedcon.rb".```
````

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow!
I notice that the command you ran doesn't quite have everything. it seems you put `brew install --build-from- ` and not `brew install --build-from-source ` that might be causing your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what you posted I have two suggestions.

Inside your the **xmedcon.rb** you have only one "end" at the final of the file. You should have another 1. The first "end" closes "def install", the second one closes the CLASS at the top.

1- So, just download this file. It's already with the right name: [xmedcon.rb](https://xmedcon.sourceforge.io/pub/macos/xmedcon.rb)

2- Install using `brew install --build-from-source xmedcon.rb` in the same directory of the file to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using `--formula` (if it's a formula), otherwise you'll get this warning that it's treated as a Cask (for example building zsh.rb):

```
Error: Failed to load cask: zsh.rb
Cask 'zsh' is unreadable: wrong constant name #<Class:0x000000015811de98>
Warning: Treating zsh.rb as a formula.
```